# Blank Input in Python

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I'm just learning about while loops and have written this code for this project that passes all qualifications except one. The one is when the user hits enter (inputs nothing) it should keep asking. I'm having trouble establishing that in the program. Code below:

```
def str_analysis(question):
    while True:   
        if question.isdigit() == True:
            if int(question) > 99:
                print (question,"is a big number!")
                break
            else:
                print (question,"is a small number!")
                break     
        if question.isalpha() == True:
            print (question,"is all alphabetical characters!")
            break
        else:
            print (question, "is neither all alpha nor all digit.")
            break


str_analysis(question = input("Enter word or integer: "))
```

I've tried putting this under

```
while True:
if question == "":
print ("")
```

in hopes it'll keep asking
but when I do this it just skips to (question, "is neither all alpha nor all digit.")

Comment: You have a `break` in every possible branch, meaning that your loop always makes exactly one iteration, no matter what you enter.

Answer (score 0):

This can be cleaned up a bit but just fixed your issue.

```html
def str_analysis(question):
    while True:

        if question.isdigit() == True:

            if int(question) > 99:
                print (question,"is a big number!")
                break

            else:
                print (question,"is a small number!")
                break


        elif question.isalpha() == True:
            print (question,"is all alphabetical characters!")
            break

        else:

            print (question, "is neither all alpha nor all digit.")
            question = input("Enter word or integer: ")





str_analysis(question = input("Enter word or integer: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while-loop to solve it:

```
question = input("Enter word or integer: ")

def str_analysis(question):
    while True:   
        if question.isdigit() == True:
            if int(question) > 99:
                print (question,"is a big number!")
                break
            else:
                print (question,"is a small number!")
                break     
        if question.isalpha() == True:
            print (question,"is all alphabetical characters!")
            break
        else:
            print (question, "is neither all alpha nor all digit.")
            break


while len(question) == 0:
    question = input("Enter word or integer: ")

str_analysis(question)
```

How it works:

Every time the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will keep asking.